# Needs Android push Notifications Details

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

Is there  any library for android push notification aprt from google cloud Messaging?

For GCM a google mailaccount is need or ?
If I don't like to use gmail account what is the alternate way achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following links: [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

You can use : **The Deacon Project**

The Deacon Project aims to produce an open-source push notifications library for the Android platform. “Deacon” is a Java class library used by Android developers to receive Push notifications from a Meteor comet web server.[“Deacon-Demo”](http://github.com/davidrea/Deacon-Demo/%29) is an Android app that is used for testing and demonstration of Deacon, and is also developed by members of the [Deacon project.](https://github.com/davidrea/Deacon)

for Amazon device without GCM:

Try: [ADM](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm.html).

**for Google Api devies(GCM):**
Here is nice tutorials for push notification its very helpful for mine also.

[Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

[Android Push Notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)

[Google docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)